# How to implement a timeout for NetworkStream.BeginWrite on CF 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp, compact-framework

I am writing asynchronously to a NetworkStream using BeginWrite and EndWrite. I want to have BeginWrite give up/time out if a certain amount of time has passed. Is there a way this be implemented in CF 3.5?

Comment: I don't think it is going to make any difference.  There are two layers to the Network Stream.  One inside the application from c# to windows interface.  Second from Windows interface to Network card.  So the asynchronous write just moves your data from c# buffer to the stream and nothing else.  So it is just moving data from memory to memory. and nothing else.  Not that the stream is emptying.

Comment: @jdweng Perhaps I was unclear. I call BeginWrite, which returns almost immediately (as expected). Some time later, the callback function passed into BeginWrite is executed, either because the write succeeded, or the connection was lost. Sometimes the write operation lags for a long time before the callback is executed. I would like to have the ability to make the write operation time out in these cases.

Comment: Really there is an issue with the TCP Acks not occurring quickly so a lot of re-sends are occurring.  This is due to the receiving end of connection running slow.  So yes adding a timer in the Network stream will at least give an indication of the issue.  See msdn example below.  In the callback Set the allDone when data is sent.  Then the timer is set before the allDone.WaitOne(); and  reset after the allDone.WaitOne(); https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginwrite(v=vs.110).aspx